# How to share an Athena Iceberg table with another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-lake-formation

I've recently been looking into the Apache Iceberg table format to reduce Athena query times on a Glue table with a large number of partitions, the additional features would be a bonus (transactions, row-level updates/deletes, time-travel queries etc). I've successfully built the tables and confirmed that they address the issue at-hand but I'd now like to be able to share the table with another AWS account, we've done this previously using Lake Formation cross-account grants and also the method described [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/security-iam-cross-account-glue-catalog-access.html) but both approaches raise errors in the alternate account when trying to query the shared table. I've also tried using a bucket policy and registering a duplicate Glue table in the other account which doesn't throw an error but no rows are found when querying.

Is this currently possible to do? I'm aware that I could achieve this by providing role access into the account with the iceberg table but this complicates interaction with the table from other services in the alternate account. Any ideas appreciated.

Edit: When querying the lake formation table I see 'Generic internal error - access denied', it's documented that Iceberg tables don't work with Lake Formation so this is expected. When querying the table shared via cross account data catalog I see 'HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Table storage descriptor is missing SerDe info' when running a SELECT query and 'FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table XXXXXXXXX. Unable to get table: java.lang.NullPointerException' when running SHOW CREATE TABLE or DESCRIBE. I can successfully run SHOW TBLPROPERTIES.

Comment: Can you update your question with the ERRORs that you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

As of now Apache Iceberg Lake Formation integration is not supported:

> Lake Formation – Integration with AWS Lake Formation is not supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg.html